# MySQL SELECT Query takes long time when fired from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures

I have a query in mysql which fetches data from single table. Table contains 4.5 million rows and all the required indices.

When I execute the query from SQLYog, it takes 0.016 seconds. But, when I embed the query into a stored procedure and execute the stores procedure, it takes 34 seconds.

Can anyone please help on why the procedure takes long time?

Execution plan of query from both with and without procedure are same.

Code of the procedure is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `centraldb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sa4_getparticipatingvehiclestset111`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sa4_getparticipatingvehiclestset111`(IN paramlicencetag VARCHAR(15),IN paramparticipantid INT)
BEGIN

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT `LicenceTag`,`ParticipantId`,(SELECT `From_Datetime` FROM participant_licencetag WHERE `LicenceTag`=p.LicenceTag AND `Participant_Indicator`=\'DN\' AND ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId limit 1) AS dn_from_datetime,(SELECT `To_Datetime` FROM participant_licencetag WHERE `LicenceTag`=p.LicenceTag AND `Participant_Indicator`=\'DN\' AND ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId limit 1) AS dn_to_datetime,(SELECT `From_Datetime` FROM participant_licencetag WHERE `LicenceTag`=p.LicenceTag AND `Participant_Indicator`=\'ED\' AND ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId limit 1) AS ed_from_datetime,(SELECT `To_Datetime` FROM participant_licencetag WHERE `LicenceTag`=p.LicenceTag AND `Participant_Indicator`=\'ED\' AND ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId limit 1) AS ed_to_datetime
 FROM `participant_licencetag` p');

    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code used in the procedure?\

Comment: I assume you ran it more than once, the first time it may have needed to parse other information.

Some other ideas:

How busy is the server? How busy was it when you ran it? There's a ton of potential factors that would create an environment where the query would take longer to run. 

Is your benchmark for the time displayed by SQLYog or MySQL?

Comment: What version off MySQL and it should be noted that stored procedures not always run better then normal querys in MySQL. but maybe you should also post an explain if there is an filesort or using temporary you should optimize your query first

Comment: @Hituptony I tested on local server. No other person was using it. The benchmarks are of SQLYog.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am using mysql version 5.6.

Comment: And we need an explain of the select query and table structure.   Your select looks like an correlated subquery what will cause an lot of full table scans and a temporary table and you should check your OS defualt tmp dir to see if it creates an myd and and myi files there if it does MySQL is creating an disk based temporary table..

Comment: Is it really necessary to use prepared statements? How long does the call to the procedure from the command line?